# How can I split a string in xslt?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to split a string at the double quotation. Input string is as follow,

```
<S>Test Example "{test1}" is "{equal}" "{test2}"</S>
```

The xslt code that I'm using is,

```
<xsl:template name="SplitString">
<xsl:param name="text" select="''" />

<xsl:variable name="tag"  select="substring-before(substring-after($text, '&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
<xsl:variable name="Remainder" select="substring-after($text, '&quot;')" />

<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$tag != ''">

<xsl:element name = "NP">
<xsl:value-of select = "$tag"/>
</xsl:element>

<!--recursive loop -->
<xsl:call-template name="SplitString">
<xsl:with-param name="text" select="$Remainder" />
</xsl:call-template>

</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The output that I'm getting is as follow,

```
<NP>{test}</NP>
<NP>is</NP>
<NP>{equal}</NP>
<NP> </NP>
<NP>{test2}</NP>
```

How can avoid the creation of empty element?
the desired output would be,

```
<NP>{test}</NP>
<NP>is</NP>
<NP>{equal}</NP>
<NP>{test2}</NP>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a condition:

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space($tag)">
  <xsl:element name = "NP">
    <xsl:value-of select = "$tag"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Note also you can reduce verbosity with literal result elements: replace `<xsl:element name="NP">..</xsl:element>` by `<NP>..</NP>` (assuming no namespaces)